# Change Kendo UI style in javascript

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

I have to change the background color of some controls in javascript. I found the way for DropDownList and ComboBox but I can't find anything about DatePicker ? What is bizarre is that there is no standard way to do it as no control seems to give you access to the same element. For exemple, to do what I want in a dropdownlist, I access the "span" :

```
$("#myDropDown").data("kendoDropDownList").span.css("background-color", "#BDD1FF");
```

While with a combobox, you have access to the "input" element :

```
$("#myComboBox").data("kendoComboBox").input.css("background-color", "#BDD1FF");
```

Yet, none of these works with the kendoDatePicker. Anyone knows the way ? I tried accessing css directly (like in JQuery) but had no luck.

**EDIT** : I need to change only a few controls in my forms, not all of them. That's why I can't override kendo CSS. I also need to apply this background only when my view model is on edit mode. Therefore, I need to be able to toggle class, that's why I'm thinking JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easies way is defining your own CSS for applying the color. You can do it in a single command as:

```
.k-input {
    background: #BDD1FF !important;
}
```

Then for using it you don't need to do anything special, just:

```
$("#myKendoDropDown").kendoDropDownList().data("kendoDropDownList");
$("#myComboBox").kendoComboBox({}).data("kendoComboBox");
$("#myDate").kendoDatePicker({});
```

It is important to note a couple of questions:

1. You cannot simply define `background-color` since KendoUI also uses background images and other background attributes, so you need to overwrite all of them.
2. `!important` is actually important since you want to overwrite posterior definitions for  `background`.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Nxv3B/

**EDIT**: If you want to do it programmatically so you can control which elements, then you should do.

```
var dd1 = $("#myKendoDropDown1").kendoDropDownList().data("kendoDropDownList");
```

For creating the widget and then for applying the styling:

```
dd1.wrapper.find(".k-input").css("background", "#BDD1FF");
```

See the fiddle modifier in here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Nxv3B/5/

Comment: I edited my question to explain why I think I can't override the kendo CSS

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do it the way above, don't worry about it being a Kendo DropDownList.  The issue is, most of the time in Document.Ready, the widget isn't ready yet.  So just treat it as if it's just a normal element on the page until it does load.  This will save you LOADS of time.

```
$("#myKendoDropDown1").css("width", 220);
```

This isn't the correct answer to this post, because this solution will not work with background-color, but it does work with other CSS.